# Select2js not working with asp.net webservice method

Tags: jquery-select2

Here is the client side script that i have used in the asp.net default.aspx page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link href="select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="select2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     var attendeeUrl = 'WebService.asmx/GetSelect2Data';       
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#select2text").select2({
            placeholder: 'Enter names',
            //Does the user have to enter any data before sending the ajax request
            minimumInputLength: 0,            
            allowClear: true,
            multiple: true,
            closeOnSelect: true,
            ajax: {
                //How long the user has to pause their typing before sending the next request
                quietMillis: 150,
                //The url of the json service
                url: attendeeUrl,
                type:'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                //Our search term and what page we are on
                data: function (term) {
                    return {
                        searchTerm: term
                    };
                },
                results: function (data) {
                    return { results: data};
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<input type="hidden" id="select2text" style="width:200px;" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Following is the server side code that i have used in my web service.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string GetSelect2Data() {

    IEnumerable<Select2Data> lst = new List<Select2Data>{
    new Select2Data{id="1",text="Smith"},
    new Select2Data{id="2",text="Brown"},
    new Select2Data{id="3",text="Gray"},
    new Select2Data{id="4",text="John"}
    };
    string result = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(lst);
    return result;
}
```

Please help me it would be very appreciable...
Thanks
Satish kumar

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your webservice method with the following code:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void GetSelect2Data() {

    IEnumerable<Select2Data> lst = new List<Select2Data>{
    new Select2Data{id="1",text="Smith"},
    new Select2Data{id="2",text="Brown"},
    new Select2Data{id="3",text="Gray"},
    new Select2Data{id="4",text="John"}
    };
    string result = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(lst);       
    this.Context.Response.Write(result);
}
```

it should work with Select2js plugin...

Thanks
Satish